# Add hoverintent to this jquery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

Is there way to add hoverinter to this jquery snippet? Currently if you hover across surrounding elements with the "wall-block-content" class they all fade in/out.

```
$(".wall-block-content").fadeTo("fast", 0);

$(".wall-block-content").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
},function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0);
});
```

Comment: Can you show an example of "surrounding elements with the wall-block-content class"? Maybe include a simple jsFiddle of what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method instead, much more solid and you can improve your animations like this:

**Update:** You can create a fake element with transparent bg and than use that for triggering targeted element's animation. **[Here is jsFiddle sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/V6DDg/8/)**

```
$(".hidden").hover(function(){
    $('.target').stop().animate({'opacity':'1','margin-top':'0px'},100);
},function(){
    $('.target').stop().animate({'opacity':'0','margin-top':'20px'},100);
});

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="target posi"></div>
    <div class="hidden posi"></div>
</div>

#wrapper { position:relative; left:0; top:0; } 
    .posi { position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; width:200px; height:200px;}
        .hidden { background:transparent; cursor:pointer; }
        .target {background:red; opacity:0;}
```

Comment: That's great, but is there a way to hide the .wall-block-content div until someone hovers over it?

Comment: @DeanElliott I've updated my answer, check out the jsFiddle please.

Comment: Your first solution was perfect apart from I just needed to hide the .wall-block-content div on page load....

Comment: @DeanElliott `$(document).ready(function( $('.myEle').hide(); ));` or you can use `css`? I am having hard times trying to understand you (:

Comment: @DeanElliott You can create a fake element which stands exact same location with target element. Than use this fake elements for triggering mouse over animations. Please inpect my updated answer carefully. `target = .wall-block-content` and `hidden = Fake Element`

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer to implement intent: http://jsfiddle.net/bxqTr/

```
$(".wall-block-content").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        timer = $this.data("timer");

    if(timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},100);
    }, 1000);
    $this.data("timer", timer);
},function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        timer = $this.data("timer");

    if(timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
     $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},100);
});
```

In this example, the user must hover over the element for at least 1 second (1000 ms) to show intent. Barlas is right though, using animate is cleaner.